# Windows Vista crashes, one of the fans might not be working

Tags: windows-vista, crash, speedfan

My computer has been crashing lately so I did a test with SpeedFan. Here's a screendump.

[image]

This isn't telling me much except that one of the fans might not be working. The picture is taking no other process except the usual.

Specs:

- AMD Phenom X3 2.10 GHz
- 3 GB RAM
- Nvidia Gforce 9600 GS

The CPU usage isn't really 40% while doing nothing – there were some processes shutting down etc. It should be around 4%.

Comment: SpeedFan is a hardware monitoring program. It doesn't test system in general. It can perform some components like HDD, nothing more. At least exact BSOD message (what was written on the blue screen after crash) or event log errors could help.

Comment: is 87 celcius a too high temp for gpu?

Comment: Your description of the problem is vague, it just consists of the words "has been crashing lately". That's really not a sufficient problem description to get useful answers. Does it crash after the same amount of time? Only under load? What kind of crash? BSOD? Freeze? You are asking as super-narrow question about details that most likely have nothing to do with your actual problem. Also, SpeedFan results when the system isn't under load don't tell us much. Temps could be low because cooling is good or because load is low. Fans could be slow because they're bad, or because load is low.

Comment: 0 rpm isn't that a little low? I thought it probably want working

Comment: @david schwartz Sorry for being unclear, herse a screenshot when putting a little presure the system(minecraft) http://imageshack.us/f/826/sefsef.jpg/ Is the third fan related to the overheating gpu?

Comment: @Jkguitar Unlikely. That's probably a motherboard fan header that has nothing connected to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ragarding your GPU temp. Max temp for videochip is about 105C. Exact temperature depends on cooling system. It is almost always high for passive systems, and should be high only under oad for active systems. What kind of system do you have?

Anyway, your temperature is acceptable under load. But if you are getting such temperature right after system start, without loading your video - you should check its cooling system and maybe clean up ot even replace the cooler.